# Python. Поиск текста внутри окна программы

Tags: python, python-2.x

Возникла необходимость, используя Python, искать текст внутри окна программы. Причём зачастую внутри `Label Box'ов`.

Вот окошко из Micro-Cap, и мне, к примеру, надо найти слово Spectrum. Как такое реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если задача только под Windows, то вам нужны функции WinAPI [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`EnumChildWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), инструмент типа [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460756.aspx) (чтобы получить информацию о классах искомых окон), а также библиотека, позволяющая вызывать эти функции (pywin32, например).

Примерный алгоритм:

1. Получить идентификатор (handle) окошка About по заголовку и классу окна (с помощью `FindWindow`). Класс окна можно узнать с помощью Spy++. Функция `FindWindowEx` позволяет найти окно по заголовку, классу окна, идентификатору родительского окна, идентификатору предыдущего дочернего окна родительского окна.
2. Получить идентификаторы дочерних окон (элементов управления) окошка About (с помощью функции `EnumChildWindows`)
3. С помощью функции `GetWindowText` получить текст дочерних окон и найти окно, содержащее искомый текст.
4. Бонус: можно найти кнопку и послать ей с помощью функции [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) сообщение о том, что по ней кликнули ([`BM_CLICK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Также есть специальная библиотека [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) для упрощения подобных задач.

**Обновление**

Небольшой пример. Не стал разбираться, как передать callback-функцию в EnumChildWindows, сделал свою аналогичную функцию на основе FindWindowEx:

```
import win32gui
def enumerate_children(parent):
    prev = None
    while True:
        cur = win32gui.FindWindowEx(parent, prev, None, None)
        if not cur:
            return
        yield cur
        prev = cur
```

Тестируем (открыто окно "о программе" блокнота):

```
>>> import win32gui
>>> wnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Блокнот: сведения')
>>> wnd
3867102
>>> [win32gui.GetWindowText(item) for item in enumerate_children(wnd)]
['', '', 'Майкрософт Windows', 'Версия 10.0 (сборка 10240)', '© Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2015 г. Все права защищены.', 'Операционная система Windows 10 Домашняя для одного языка и пользовательский интерфейс в ней защищены правами на товарные знаки и иные объекты интеллектуальной собственности в США и других странах.', '', '', 'Microsoft', 'Microsoft', 'ОК']
```

Скриншот окна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть текста по каким-то причинам не извлеклась, но в вашем случае, думаю, проблем не будет.

**Еще одно:** в msdn написано, что `GetWindowText` не работает с элементами управления окна чужого процесса, и текст чужих элементов управления можно получить только с помощью посылки сообщения `WM_GETTEXT`, однако, как видим, через `win32gui.GetWindowText` можно получить текст чужих элементов управления. Возможно, просто внутри библиотеки pywin32 `GetWindowText` реализован через посылку сообщения. Но насколько я помню, особых проблем с получением текста любого окна через `GetWindowText` без оберток, например на Си, никогда не было.

Comment: А разве `GetWindowText` поможет найти текст в окне? Насколько я понял из описания, функция возвращает текст в заголовке.

Comment: @HEV, плохо читали описание: "If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied." (Если указанное окно - элемент управления, то возвращается текст в нем)